# How to toggle between two methods execution on click of a same <a> tag in CI

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I have an `<a>` tag like this

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url("// My method's Url"); ?>">First Name</a>
```

and I have two different functions in my controller given below.

```
public function index_fname_Asc()
{
    $this->load->view("admin/myview1");
}

public function index_fname_Dsc()
{
    $this->load->view("admin/myview2");
}
```

Note: these two functions are in the same controller of CI.

I want to toggle these function execution on Click of the above `<a>` tag. This means that when I click for the first time it should execute my `index_fname_Asc()` function and next time it should execute my `index_fname_Dsc()` function and so on.

Comment: you can use `session` to handle this

Comment: Is your link part of both view templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could easily switch between these href's by using data from the controller. 
For example:

```
public function index_fname_Asc()
{
  $data['sort'] = 'ASC';  
  $this->load->view("admin/myview1",$data);

}

public function index_fname_Dsc()
{
  $data['sort'] = 'DESC';  
  $this->load->view("admin/myview2");
}
```

Then in the view:

```
if($sort == "ASC"){
 echo "<td <a href=" . site_url("// My method's Url") .">First Name</a></td>"
}else{


 //Other href
 }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have only single <a>. i have to execute both functions on this single <a> tag's click event

Comment: I know, that's why you change the href accordingly. If the previous method was index_fname_Asc(), make the href point to index_fname_Desc() and the other way around

Comment: Awesome solution. like a painkiller :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use server side session for this , anchor tag link to `index_fanme_Asc` url .

```
public function index_fname_Asc()
{
   // i didn't test .. you can change into ci session 
   if ( isset($_SESSION['hasClicked']) && $_SESSION['hasClicked'] ){

        $this->index_fname_Dsc();
        return ;
   }

   $_SESSION['hasClicked'] = true;

   $this->load->view("admin/myview1");
}

public function index_fname_Dsc()
{
     $_SESSION['hasClicked'] = false;

     $this->load->view("admin/myview2");
}
```

hope this will works